# how to set the location of lable in c# , i want to use some point in my project to set the location

Tags: c#

```
Graphics gr;
gr = CreateGraphics();

Pen p = new Pen(System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(r.Next(255), r.Next(255), r.Next(255)), 1.1f);
Point p1 = new Point(array1[currentadd], dx);

Point p2 = new Point(array1[currentadd], dx = dx + 7);
gr.DrawLine(p, p1, p2);
```

now i have drawn a line and i want to write the info of points where the line is connecting them  ...so i want so set label position to write the point position ... but how?

Comment: [MSDN is a great resource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.location.aspx)

Comment: Finding properties like `Location`, `Size`, `Text` and so on should be pretty trivial, IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You should take a look at this document here at MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287522%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

In particular something you'll notice in the example is this line:

```
formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 200, 200);
```

This is doing five different things:

- First it will call our `Drawing Object`.
- Second and third are our drawing points.
- Fourth and fifth are the floating location.

This will obviously allow you to create some bounded locations.  Obviously, if you've generated a class that will handle this initially to build it.  Then when you call this object in another class you can `position`, `dock`, `location`, and `anchor` to that form you've called it in.

[Please bear in mind that this assumes a basic line, but you can make more complex things as found here on the MSDN.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287524%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

**Potential Problem:**

*If you utilize the methodology in the example directly on your **Form** please bare in mind that the* `this` *will bind to the current scope of the object that the* `this` *is represented for.  An example, if this code was on a button:*

```
Pen myPen = Pen(Color.Red);
Graphics formGraphics = this.CreateGraphics();
formGraphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 100, 200, 200);
```

*Then it will be bind the points based on the location of the button object in this case.*

Hopefully that helps point you in the right direction.

**Update:**

Based on your question, it sounds like your trying to place the line either above or below a standard label.  Which can be done quite simple, such as:

```
// Define Label
Label i = new Label();

// Create our Line.
Pen iPen = Pen(Color.Red);
Graphics iGraphics = i.CreateGraphics();
iGraphics.DrawLine(iPen, 0, 250, 0, 0);

// Dock to Bottom of Form
i.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
```

Then if you change the location at any point with a button, or you modify the text within a loop your line will remain bound to your `label` object.  Is that not what you wanted?

Comment: Your trying to draw a line, then insert a label ontop of it correct?  This can do exactly that if you bind the line underneath label then when you use a basic `dock` or `anchor` or any other location utility it will move to the desired location.